# Derivative graphs

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

How would the approximate graph of the derivative of the following function look?

[image]

First of all, I don't know where to start from. I am able to relate to the fact that the derivative's graph will have negative values wherever there is a ngegative slope and positive values wherever there is a positive slope. So I thought for the first curved part (starting from the left), the gradient goes less and less positive until the turning point, where it goes more and more negative until it becomes undefined. I'm stuck there.

Thanks in advance,
Ramana

Comment: What you've said is fine.  You can go further, though.  For instance, you can see to the right of the first maximum, the function decreases very quickly.  Therefore, the derivative will not only be negative, it will have a large absolute value.  You can show this qualitatively in your sketch, and see what you think about the other parts of the graph.

Comment: @ saulspatz. So when can I say the graph of the derivative will be a curve rather than a straight line? If not this function, what other functions? Examples? I'm just trying to get the feel for the relationship between the function's graph and it's derivative's graph.

Comment: The derivative of a curve will generally not be a straight line. Only a quadratic has a linear derivative.

Comment: The only time the graph of the derivative will be a straight line is when the original function is a polynomial of degree at most $2$.  The only other thing I can think of in general about the relation is that the function will generally be "smoother" than the derivative.  If the function is the position of a car traveling in a straight line, and the derivative is the speed, when you stamp on the brake or the gas pedal, the speed changes much more abruptly than the position does, and the acceleration (the second derivative) more abruptly yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this [image]

From left to right (x).

1. The slope is infinite as graph is almost vertical.
2. The slope decreases and becomes zero. - hence the derivative is zero.
3. Again slope decreases and function becomes vertical - derivative tends to - inf - and not defined.
4. Slope starts increasing and becomes less negative.
5. At x = 0 - slope is zero.
6. At +ve x - the curvature changes from concave up to concave down - hence maxima
7. Another place where gradient zero
8. Gradient again goes to -ve infinity

Comment: @Ramana please have a look at this

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense.